# [Mongodb]Get document if value list is intersection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have user docs that have a list of intruments that each user plays

```
User = new mongoose.schema(){
    // skiped stuff
    instruments: [String]
    // more skipped stuff
}
```

my path function takes in a list of instruments and I want all the docs where a user plays any instrument in the input instrument list

I have been trying to use

```
{instruments:{
    $elemMatch: {
        $in: inputInstrumentList // thought something like this would work :/
    }
}
```

but that is only giving me errors

pre-emptive thanks for any and all help

Comment: Try `User.find({ "instruments": { "$in": inputInstrumentList  } }).exec(callback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [chridam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122005/chridam) showed, I was overthinking that matter and $in works perfectly